# Questions, answers, and ... articles?

Tags: support

I just noticed that where user profile pages used to display (something like) "view all questions and answers," they now say "view all questions, answers, **and articles**" (emph. mine); see the image below, directly beneath the "Top posts" header.

What exactly is an "article" in this context? The relevant link gives a 404 error for each user I've tried. Is this a feature in the process of being added, or something else?

Note that this is only something visible when looking at *another user's* profile. E.g. if I look at my own profile (while logged in) I see no mention of articles. (This is why in the image below I'm logged out.)

[image]

Comment: Corresponding bug report on MSE: [Articles on MSE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371837/articles-on-mse)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ah, interesting! And at StackOverflow the articles link *does* do something - e.g. [this randomly picked user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael?tab=articles) has no articles, but we nonetheless don't see a 404 error. So is this something that's really only for SO and got accidentally pushed onto all sites, or what?

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/03/find-knowledge-faster-new-articles-features/

Comment: I have no idea if this was "accidentally" pushed to users off of SO.  I don't know anything beyond what is in that currently unanswered Meta SE post. :\

Comment: @XanderHenderson Fair enough, thanks!

Comment: Also see [this CM post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411051/16712865) (in particular the last sentence) and the rest of that thread. So with minimal supporting evidence, my speculation is that Articles will be rolled out network-wide some time in the future, and today's release is a technical error. On a more specific note, if the Articles plan is true then it would be beneficial to this community as it can solve a lot of duplicate post issues.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire It will also pose more moderation challenges, e.g. cranks will now be article-blogging  their "proofs" of FLT, $\,3x\!+\!1$, etc in hopes of benefiting from the high page rank of SE.

Comment: This announcement on Meta Stack Overflow also has one paragraph on Articles: [Beta release of Collectives™ on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408585) (BTW the announcement has now score $-271$.) There were also two recent bug reports on meta.SO: [/articles leaks top secret AudioBubble collective articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412862) and [Why doesn't the /articles page show that an article has a negative score?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412920).

Comment: It sounds like an interesting idea, **IF** we can use the feature to handle FAQs. But we also need the ability to use the existence of an article on the theme as a reason to close and delete. Also, the bar for writing and publishing an article needs to be rather high. Like 3 or more gold badge owners approve of it. Otherwise we run into the kind of problems Bill Dubuque brought up.

Comment: A staff member [confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371837/articles-on-mse?noredirect=1#comment1242245_371837) on Meta SE that this is a bug and that this will be fixed soon.

Comment: The feature is probably applicable not only to StackOverflow but to StackOverflow for Teams private sites above the free tier, aka the [Business tier of Teams](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4460658-latest-releases-for-the-business-tier-of-teams).

Comment: Interestingly, I just noticed this for the first time within a minute or two before seeing your question!

Comment: The "Articles" tab has now been removed from all sites (except SO). See the [answer by staff member Yari](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371837) to the corresponding bug report on Meta SE.